# Clickable links imagecreatefrompng

Tags: php, image

At this moment i'm trying to create a dynamic PHP image, and i'm not really sure if it is even possible to have clickable links in the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$image = "hotelview_val13.png";
$src = 'pixel.png';
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.')); 
$font = 'font.ttf';  //Ubuntu font
$im = imagecreatefrompng($image);

imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

imagealphablending($src_to_copy, true);
imagesavealpha($src_to_copy, true);

imagealphablending($pg, true);
imagesavealpha($pg, true);

$wc = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$red = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 255, 0, 0);
$blk = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

{
    imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 45, 310, $blk, $font , "<A HREF=\"link.php\"     TARGET=\"_blank\">Link</A>");
    imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 45, 330, $blk, $font , "Veel plezier ;)");
}



header("Content-Type: image/png");
Imagepng($im);
ImageDestroy ($im);
?>
```

What i'm trying to do is to make a clickable link. I've tried to just simply put  into the code, but that doesn't work because it displays the code as plain text. Is it possible? If it is, how does it work?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed links in an image. The only way to make a region of an image clickable is, when viewed in a browser, to use an HTML [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map).

Comment: You can't wrap an `img` tag in an `a` tag?

Comment: Of course you can. I meant, make a region of an image clickable, not the whole image. (Edited my answer)

Comment: @Chris: that's what I'm saying.